# Asymptotic variance for Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\hat{\mu_t}(f)=\frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^{t} f(X_i)$ is an estimator for a finite, irreducible Markov chain $\{X_t\}$ with its stationary distribution $\pi$. In addition, assume the estimator is unbiased.

Then, let's consider the asymptotic variance, which is given by

$\sigma^2 (f) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} t \cdot Var(\hat{\mu_t})=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t} E \{ [\sum_{i=1}^{t} f(X_i) - E_{\pi}(f)]^2 \}$.

Moreover, assume that we have another Markov chain $\{X_t^{'}\}$ with the same stationary distribution $\pi$ as one for $\{X_t\}$, but have different transition matrix and the estimator $\hat{\mu_t}^{'}(f)=\frac{1}{t} \sum_{i=1}^{t} f(X_i^{'})$

In this case, can the asymptotic variances for  $\hat{\mu_t}^{'}$ and $\hat{\mu_t}$ be different?

I think it should be same due to 1) the same stationary distribution and 2) the same form of the estimator function, but some papers regard them as different (in my understanding).

Comment: They are different since different transition matrices have different correlations between $f(X_i)$ and $f(X_{i+1})$. For example $[1-\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ has high correlation and hence high variance while [0,1;1,0] has a low (negative in fact) correlation and hence a much lower variance. To take it to the extreme, consider $[1,0;0,1]$ and starting in stationary distribution. Estimator will be unbiased but its asymptotic variance will be infinite.

Comment: That's why if you are building a Markov chain with a given stationary distribution $\pi$ to estimate $E_{\pi}f$, you want correlations between $f(X_i)$ and $f(X_{i+1})$ as low as possible.